# Pass derived classes in a function with base case as parameter

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am writing a C# program that is a basic text rpg game.  When I save the game, I want to pass the character into a save function that will then get the data from the character and write it into an xml file.  I have one base class **Character** and three derived classes:**Knight**, **Rogue**, and **Wizard**. They each have a special int that I want to write to an xml file.

```
private void Save(Character c, string file) {
    //Sample part of writing the data
    XmlNode nodeName = playerData.CreateElement("name");
    nodeName.AppendChild(playerData.CreateTextNode(c.name));
    nodeDetails.AppendChild(nodeName);
}
```

I want to pass in a **Knight**, **Rogue**, or **Wizard** into this function and be able to get any variables in the derived classes that are not in the base class.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if all or some subtypes end up having different properties that can't be cleanly pulled up into the base type, consider looking at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern for double dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through the use of casting.

```
private void Save(Character c, string file)
{
    if(c is Knight)
    {
        k = (Knight)c;
        // Do whatever with k
    }
    else if (c is Rogue)
    {
        r = (Rogue)c;
        // Do whatever with k
    }
}
```

However, this undermines the polymorphic structure you have set up - the whole point of polymorphism is that you *shouldn't have to do this.*

It would be better practice if the `Character` class had an `abstract` or `virtual` method that returned the data needed to save.  Each subclass would override this method to return the required information (including anything special for that subclass), so you would never need to check what type of `Character` was passed in.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I'm going to take your advice and add a method in the base class to override in my derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rogue rogue = new Rogue();
            Save(rogue, "1234");
        }
        static void Save(Character c, string file)
        {
            if(c.GetType() == typeof(Knight))
            {
            }
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Rogue))
            {
            }
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Wizard))
            {
            }


        }
    }

    public class Character
    {
    }
    public class Knight : Character
    {
    }
    public class Rogue : Character
    {
    }
    public class Wizard : Character
    {
    }
}
```